# Parse error on input '='

Tags: haskell

I keep getting this message, what am I doing wrong?

```
quadrant :: Float -> Float -> Quadrant
quadrant x y
    |x = 0 && y = 0 = Origin
    |x > 0 && y = 0 = X_ Axis_Positive
    |x > 0 && y > 0 = Quadrant_1
    |x = 0 && y > 0 = Y_ Axis_Positive
    |x < 0 && y > 0 = Quadrant_2
    |x < 0 && y = 0 = X_ Axis_Negative
    |x < 0 && y < 0 = Quadrant_3
    |x = 0 && y < 0 = Y_ Axis_Negative
    |x > 0 && y < 0 = Quadrant_4
    |otherwise = error "Program error: Non-Exhaustive guards in function: quadrant"
```

Answer (score 7):

The operator to test for equality is `==`, where `=` is part of the language grammar.

Comment: `(==)` isn't part of the language syntax but part of the `Prelude`. It's defined with `infix 4 ==; (==) :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> Bool`

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with the fundamental answer - but I was hoping for refinement on the last few words, and possibly a reference (e.g. as to "what" `=` is).

Comment: Semantics. It's probably more accurate to say grammar. I'm referring to the rules of the language structure, and not the whole language itself.

Comment: @user2864740 `(==)` is a type class method that is defined in the Haskell standard library and `=` is a fundamental part of the Haskell language itself. `=` cannot be broken down further, in the same sense as `{` and `}` in C/C++/C#/Java/etc and `:` in Python.